# How to use mx:TabNavigator in flex 4.5 Mobile project

Tags: air, adobe, flash-builder, flex4.5

I have a problem. In Flex Mobile project, I can not use the usual mx:TabNavigator. I need to dynamically create tabs and close them.
With s:TabbedViewNavigator I can not dynamically create "Views", and tabs for them. I could not close these tabs.
what can I do to use tabNavigator?
Thanks.

P.S. I use FlashBuilder 4.5 with AIR 2.6 SDK

Answer (score 0):

Mobile Flex project support only a very limited amount of the old mx components, the TabNavigator is not one of them.

For a dynamic tab navigation use a for example a `ButtonBar` linked with a `ViewNavigator`.